# Advantages of using Redis Cache over other Caching mechanisms

Tags: azure, caching, azure-redis-cache

While Azure Redis Cache gains popularity day by day, one question that remains is what is the advantage of using it over other Caching mechanisms? I failed to get a comprehensive explanation on this.

Comment: what kind of other caching mechanism do you have in mind? Without knowing your use case it is hard to tell if it is a good fit or not.

Comment: Are you looking for a comparison of Azure Redis to self-hosting Redis?  Or are you looking for a comparison of Redis to something other than Redis?

Comment: either way this question is off topic and heavily opinion based